# I am using IntelliJ and I am unable to output on it, how do I do that?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I am trying to output a scatter plot graph from mySQl on the IntelliJ GUI, however I have no idea how to do that and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please elaborate on what graph? For what? Have you checked https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/creating-diagrams.html ?

Comment: it is a line for tank level against time